# Having trouble using I2C to write and read

Tags: c, mbed

```
Serial pc(USBTX,USBRX);
I2C i2c(p9,p10);

void writing(int val) {
      i2c.start();
    i2c.write(0b10100000); //address 1010xxxx, r/w=0 write
    
  i2c.write(0); //address inside the chip
    i2c.write(val); //storing values
    i2c.stop();
      wait_ms(6);
    }

void reading() {
    
    int data;
    //reading
    i2c.start();
    i2c.write(0b10100000);
    i2c.write(0);
    i2c.start();
    i2c.write(0b10100001); //address 1010xxxx, r/w=0 read
    data = i2c.read(0);
    i2c.stop();
    pc.printf ("%c\n\r",data);
    
    }
```

I've tried assigning specific address to I2C object by `const int addr = 0x52;` It does not seem to work. I also tried changing the  `0b10100001`  to `0b10100000` but no luck at all. What I am doing wrong here? Basically `i2c.write(0)` is writing to the address and `i2c.write(1)` is reading the address.

Comment: I am using Tera Term to reading the outputs all i get are `i` and 160 and 255 i assume the numbers are address and the `i` is specific letter on the mbed?

Comment: Have you tried with ‘write (int address, const char * data, int length, bool repeated = false)´ instead of sending single bytes ? Are you sure that you’ve set the proper frequency ?